# drag and drop using jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to interchange the positions of my div's using drag and drop. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3HWpk/)

```
<div class="component">
    <p>paragraph1</p>
</div>

<div class="component">
    <p>paragraph2</p>
</div>

jQuery('.component').draggable({revert: "invalid"});
```

Comment: I think you want to use a sortable to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/3HWpk/2/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery('.component').draggable($( "#component" ).droppable);

use this JQuery, may help